# Execute function from object property

Tags: node.js

i have a little problem with my code.
My expectation is, when i get the object **reqHeaders** to the function **getQueryData**
i want that the property UUID will execute the function createToken().

currently, when i running the program, it happens only at the init( first time ).

```
  const createToken = () => {
  // some logics...
  return `${token}`;
};

const reqHeaders = {
  UUID: **createToken()**,
  "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
};

const getQueryData = query => {
  return axiosInstance
    .post("/someAddress", { selectQuery: query }, { headers: **reqHeaders** })
    .then(response => {
    // some logs...
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
     //some logs....
      return error;
    });
}
};
module.exports = getQueryData;
```

thank you,
Raz.

Comment: You need to move the declaration of reqHeaders inside getQueryData

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to move the object creation inside the body of the function.

```
const createToken = () => {
  // some logics...
  return `${token}`;
};

const getQueryData = query => {
  return axiosInstance
    .post("/someAddress", { selectQuery: query }, { headers: {
  UUID: **createToken()**,
  "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
} })
    .then(response => {
    // some logs...
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
     //some logs....
      return error;
    });
}
};

module.exports = getQueryData;
```

Now each time you run the function new req headers will be created and hence the UUID. What you did previously created an object once and then use the same object for each function call.

Comment: thanks for your comment. but i need it in an global object cause i plan to export it and use it in other parts in mt code....

Comment: Well if you need a global object, this won't work as you want. 

You can move this object into a separate faction e.g. `createReqHeaders` and call it each time you need to get the req headers.